# MySQL: SQL Syntax and other errors only in Linux server

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, xampp, lamp

Please have a look in below SQL code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `xxx`.`reminder` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xxx`.`reminder` (
  `idreminder` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `patient_idpatient` INT NOT NULL,
  `remind_about` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `reminder_time` TIME NOT NULL,
  `reminder_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `repeat_action` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `last_updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idreminder`),
  INDEX `fk_Reminder_patient1_idx` (`patient_idpatient` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Reminder_patient1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`patient_idpatient`)
    REFERENCES `myglukose`.`patient` (`idpatient`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When I copy this into PhpMyAdmin, I get the following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`
```

I have 2 questions.

1. I really don't spot the error, what is it?
2. Important thing is that these auto generated SQL code from MySQL Work Bench!! All of these worked very well in Windows with XAMPP and all these issues are with Ubuntu running LAMP.Not only this error,in some tables I am also getting the error `#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause`

Why all of this with Ubuntu (14.04)? I installed LAMP by following this - http://devoncmather.com/setting-aws-ec2-instance-lamp-git/

How to fix this, if any issue with installation, any recommended alternate tutorial?

Comment: One thing might be different mysql versions,other thing might be that phpmyadmin is a POS,run those statements one by one.

Comment: It looks like it's using backticks instead of single quote. Try changing those to single quotes/removing them. Phpadmin can be retarded sometimes.